# AWK gaps between cells

Tags: string, bash, text, awk, gaps-in-data

I have a problem, please could you help me?
I have the .txt file I use the awk code to separate columns using the tab delimited function.
I receive the align columns, but if some information missing, the whole row turn left and information are  shifted to another column. Please could you help me? How could I 
incorporate to this code? Thank you so much..

```
#!/bin/bash

for f 
in *.vcf; 
do awk 'BEGIN {OFS = "\t"}
        /^##/ {next}
        /^#/ {sub(/^#/,"",$1)}
        {$1=$1; print}
    ' "$f" > "${f/%vcf/tsv}"
done


> INPUT:
> 
> CHROM    ID    REF   ALT 
  chr1    235     A     B 
  chr2     A      B
  chr3    225     B
```

> OUTPUT:

```
  CHROM    ID   REF   ALT  
  chr1    235    A     B 
  chr2     .     A     B 
  chr3    225    .     B
```

Comment: How are the columns aligned? Can you post sample data?

Comment: You can check if the number of fields (NF) is equal to the one expected, otherwise skip the row.

Comment: btw, script coming from http://stackoverflow.com/a/19451399/1983854

Comment: Yes It is no my script, mr. glen is author, but is it a problem? If it is I am so sorry.

Comment: The columns are separate only by tab delimited

Comment: So original `.vcf` files are not tab delimited already?

Comment: If you have problems with alignment, you might have a look at this http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47832/is-there-a-simple-command-for-outputting-tab-delimited-columns-in-bash

Comment: Yes I have to tab delimit an after this find the gaps (empty fields) and sort it to right column with right header.

Comment: You really need to add a small, clear example of an input and desired output.

Comment: How do you propose to figure out which field is missing?  Are the ID's always numeric? Are the REF's always a single alpha? You need to clearly spell out your requirements if you want help from us.

Comment: ID is in format "rs2013202" and REF and ALT are often single alpha, but unfortunately sometimes have more alphas.

Answer (score 2):

The problem contains ambiguities. Looking at the data:

```
chr1    235     A     B 
chr2     A      B
chr3    225     B
```

perhaps in the `chr2` row, we can guess that the `ID` column is missing because `ID`s are numbers. We are missing one column and it's the numeric one so it must be `ID`.

But in the third row, how do we know that the `REF` column is missing, rather than `ALT`?

If `ALT` is never missing, then it's simple. But if either could be missing, it may be impossible.

In any case, before you can write the program code to renormalize the data into proper columns, you have to be able to articulate the rules for identifying what columns are missing, or else recognize that it is impossible and give up.

You may simply have to go upstream and find a better source of the same data which doesn't have munged columns.

Comment: the ALT never missing